# How to get the status of a request by another request?

Tags: java, servlets

Let me explain what I am doing first:

I have a servlet that handles some `GET`, `POST` and `PUT` requests.

Now on my `PUT` request I am saving a file from the `request.inputStream`. Now I want to do some things like I issue another `GET` request that can give me the status of reading the input stream of that previous request. I can issue an `PUT` request that can put some binary data with range for that file I am saving previously. Or I can send a DELETE request that will cancel the upload.

How can I do that? How can I access one request from another?

Comment: do u mean keep track of progress file uploading ?

Comment: almost. i just need access to one servlet request to another request. :)

Comment: Why? The first request returns its own status. Until then, it is in progress, and doesn't have a status.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HttpSession object on the request and save the bytes read on the InputStream.

The session attribute will be accessible on the following request.

Comment: Then how can i cancel the upload if an DELETE request is issued. :)

Comment: @Sadlil Err, stop writing the upload request? Why do you need a second request for this?